# What is the difference between free and paid version of OpenALPR?

Tags: openalpr

recently, I have come across a project that requires license plate recognition, and have found a open-source software named OpenALPR. yet, I am curious about the difference between the free version on github, and the paid version on their official website, could anyone clarify this for me? thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question. Contact the publisher of the product to ask for differences.